# Ionic Network plugin doesn't identify connection until Wifi turned on/off

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

My app is on Ionic 3 and I installed the [Network Plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/network/).

I've put it on my **Login.ts** and goes like this:

**login.ts**

```
private SUB_networkConnect: any;
private SUB_networkDisconnect: any;
private HAS_CONNECTION: boolean;

constructor( private network: Network ){
    this.SUB_networkConnect = this.network.onConnect().subscribe(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.HAS_CONNECTION = true;
            console.log(this.HAS_CONECTION);
        }, 3000);
    });

    this.SUB_networkDisconnect = this.network.onDisconnect().subscribe(() => {
        this.HAS_CONNECTION = false;
        console.log(this.HAS_CONECTION);
    });
}
```

I use this, cause the first (ever) login must download assets and other stuff for the user.

If I don't have connection I'm not allowing user authentication.

**So when I turned off then turned on Wifi it starts trigger the console and I cant auth, because the flag HAS_CONNECTION is used on a conditional that let me continue or not**

Do you guys know how to handle this?

I also tried put it on app.component.ts, no success either

Comment: @KevinDias just because the HAS_CONNECTION is a flag used on a conditional. If i have connection continue auth, else don't even try.... No errors, thats the regular procedure :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Rafael de Castro, as I can see, your problem is not in Login but the detection of connection presence (Wifi or not).

But in your code, you do not check it is connected but waits for an event to determine if it has a connection or not in you variable this.HAS_CONNECTION!

Try to put this line

```
this.HAS_CONNECTION = (this.network.type === 'wifi' || this.network.type === '3g' || this.network.type === '4g');
```